# TopN aggregations on spring-data-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to implement a grouping with a TopN aggregation operator using spring-data-mongo and I am lost on how to do it.

I know what I want from the POV of MongoDB. It's something like this:

```
[ { 
    $match: { 
      field000: { $regex: ".*MATCHTHIS.*" }, 
      created: { $lte: new Date("2030-05-25T00:00:00.000+00:00" ) } 
    }, 
  }, 
  { 
     $group: { 
       _id: "$field001", 
       field001s: { 
         $topN: { 
           output: ["$field002", "$created"], 
           sortBy: { created: -1, }, 
           n: 1, 
         }
       }
     }
    }]
```

Meaning ... for the set of documents already filtered by the $match clause; group by field001, order each bucket by created desc, and pick the top (1). So the most recently created documents for each group category.

I find problems to translate this into spring-data-mongo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of research, I realized this question is probably easily solvable on spring-data-mongodb most recent versions since "topN" aggregation operator is implemented. However in my case upgrading the stack to support that version is not an option.

On the other hand, if you are using repositories then the @Charchit Kapoor solution is probably the best one.

If you want to stick with mongo template it can be done this way:

```
    AggregateIterable<Document> result = mongoOps.getCollection(COLLECTION_NAME).aggregate(Arrays.asList(new Document("$match",
        new Document("field000",
          new Document("$regex", ".*REGEXP_FIELD_000.*"))
          .append("created",
            new Document("$lte",
              new java.util.Date(1685318400000L)))),
      new Document("$group",
        new Document("_id", "$field001")
          .append("Field0001s",
            new Document("$topN",
              new Document("output", Arrays.asList("$field002", "$created"))
                .append("sortBy",
                  new Document("created", -1L))
                .append("n", 1L))))));
```

You can split this into different methods for better readability.

Answer (score 1):

Using `MongoRepository`, you can specify the pipeline using, `@Aggregate` annotation. Something like this:

```
@Aggregation(pipeline = {"{ $match: { field000: { $regex: '?0' }, created: { $lte: '?1' } },}, { $group: { _id: '$field001', field001s: { $topN: { output: ['$field002', '$created'], sortBy: { created: -1, }, n: 1}}}}"})
Object filterAndGroup(String regex, ZonedDateTime created);
```

Note that I have parameterized the search regex and date value. Please update it accordingly, along with the return type of the function. Using `MongoTemplate`, you can try something along these lines.

```
MatchOperation matchStage = Aggregation.match(
   new Criteria("field000").regex(".*MATCHTHIS.*")
     .and(new Criteria("created").lte(YOUR_JAVA_DATE_OBJECT))
);
ProjectionOperation projectStage = Aggregation.project("field002", "created", "field001");
SortOperation sortByCreatedDesc = sort(Sort.by(Direction.DESC, "created"));
GroupOperation groupStage = Aggregation.group("field001").first("$$ROOT").as("field001s");

Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
  matchStage, projectStage, sortByCreatedDesc, groupStage);
AggregationResults<XYZModel> result = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
  aggregation, "collectionName", XYZModel.class);
```

Note that, I have added two new stages for `Projection` and `Sorting`, as `$topN` is not yet supported by [Spring Data MongoDB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/GroupOperation.html), so I am projecting the necessary fields, then sorting by `created`, and then grouping the document and picking the first one in each group.

Note: The answer is not tested by me, so you will have to try it out and adjust it.

Comment: Thanks! I am not using repositories in this case but MongoTemplate.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. However according docs the topN should be supported (!). Please look `Table 1. Aggregation Operators currently supported by Spring Data MongoDB` at `https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/main/src/main/asciidoc/reference/aggregation-framework.adoc`

Comment: Ok. Part of the source of the problem is that topN aggregation was added on spring-data-mongodb 4.0.0 and I am using a previous version, so thats why I could never found how to do it in my code.

Comment: Got it. Seems like I was looking at the wrong documentation link. This is the one you might be looking at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/SelectionOperators.Top.html @Rafael

Comment: Ok. At this point in my development, I can't afford upgrading all the stack. Do you think this approach might be feasible? 

```
Aggregation.stage is a shortcut for registering a pipeline stage by providing its JSON or Bson representation.
```

This is the example in docs ...
```
Aggregation.stage("""
    { $search : {
        "near": {
          "path": "released",
          "origin": { "$date": { "$numberLong": "..." } } ,
          "pivot": 7
        }
      }
    }
""");
```

Comment: Absolutely, you can use it this way. If your MongoDB has support for `topN` operator, then it should do the trick for you.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the support. If you wanna update your answer including the `topN` operator and the `Aggregation.stage` alternatives I will happily accept it as correct.

Comment: Unluckily `Aggregation.stage` is also not available until 4.0 so I neither can use that option.

Comment: Then I think you can try my current solution as per the current circumstances, it should work.